# Create a property that work similar to Django fields(The property wrongly acts as class attribute)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, properties

I created a function that instantiates a property that encapsulates some  communication:

```
def orion_field(name, field=None):
    def getter(self,):
        return self.get(name)

    def setter(self, value):
        self.set(name, value)

    return property(getter, setter)
```

I want to include it in my Django models in a similar way to Django fields:

```
class KPI(models.Model):
    orion_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, 
                                max_length=10)
    data = JSONField(blank=True, default={})
    name = orion_field("name")

    def set(self, attribute, value):
        self.data[attribute]= value
        # Ugly code removed that send stuff to server

    def get(self, attribute):
        # Ugly code removed that may(or may not) bring stuff from server
        return self.data[attribute]
```

The communication code works great but I noticed that these new properties work at class level.

```
    orion_entity1 = KPI()
    orion_entity2 = KPI()
    orion_entity1.name = "Babar"
    print(orion_entity2.name) 
    >>> Babar
```

I suppose at some point Django converts class fields into instance fields. I searched their code but I got lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a mutable dict `{}` as the default. Use `dict` instead, then a separate empty dictionary will be instantiated for each instance.

```
data = JSONField(blank=True, default=dict)
```

See the note in the [JSONField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) for more info.

Comment: I was so blinded with the property that I didn't look at the dictionary. I'm going to change the title to reflect the real problem. Thanks you!